# differentiate rectangles over circles (python-openCV )

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a task to detect and recognize road signs from a live video for a **blind pedestrian**. I have implemented the process, but got stuck in a place.

What I need to do is differentiate rectangular shapes over circular shapes. for that I currently trying to follow following method.

1. get the Region of Interest

   2. detect how many vertices in the drawn shapes have(using Ramer Douglas Peuker Algorithm[which was initially built in method cv2.ApproxPolyDP()})
   3. if number of vertices are 4 then it is a triangle, otherwise it "can be" a circle.

But the problem is, I am receiving number of vertices are 14 when checking for a triangular shaped object.)
My supervisors asked me to reinvent the wheel of Ramer Douglas Peuker and do it by myself. 
 I need to know **is there a method to do so(Re invent Ramer Douglas Peuker or I mostly welcome any other ideas)**

the image will shown in follow.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can extract the area and the perimeter of the shapes you can calculate the [shape’s circularity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_factor_(image_analysis_and_microscopy)#Circularity) and use this to determine the shape.